# Oracle Dataguard old sequences

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-12c, dataguard

After having set up a dataguard environment with Oracle 12c I notice that when I execute the following command in the primary it shows me the archivelogs:

```
select sequence#, first_time, next_time, applied 
    from v$archived_log 
    order by sequence#;
```

```
1 07/12/2019 16:15:59 07/12/2019 21:05:14
2 07/12/2019 21:05:14 07/12/2019 21:30:24
3 07/12/2019 21:30:24 07/12/2019 21:30:26
4 07/12/2019 21:30:26 07/13/2019 0:43:03
...

71 06/08/2019 10:51:15 06/08/2019 10:58:11
71 06/08/2019 10:51:15 06/08/2019 10:58:11
72 06/08/2019 10:58:11 06/08/2019 12:30:50
72 06/08/2019 10:58:11 06/08/2019 12:30:50
73 06/08/2019 12:30:50 06/08/2019 12:40:54
73 06/08/2019 12:30:50 06/08/2019 12:40:54
10771 05/16/2019 14:40:40 05/16/2019 14:41:28
10772 05/16/2019 14:41:28 05/16/2019 14:42:55
10773 05/16/2019 14:42:55 05/16/2019 14:44:01
...

10780 05/16/2019 14:51:59 05/16/2019 14:53:33
10781 05/16/2019 14:53:33 05/16/2019 14:54:42
10782 05/16/2019 14:54:42 05/16/2019 14:56:18
```

Then the same command in the standby, I only have:

```
select sequence#, first_time, next_time, applied 
    from v$archived_log 
    order by sequence#;
```

```
66 05/08/2019 15:42:25 05/08/2019 16:41:02 YES
67 05/08/2019 16:41:02 05/08/2019 16:41:03 YES
68 05/08/2019 16:41:03 05/08/2019 21:30:26 YES
69 08/05/2019 21:30:26 08/05/2019 21:30:27 YES
70 08/05/2019 21:30:27 06/08/2019 10:51:15 YES
71 06/08/2019 10:51:15 06/08/2019 10:58:11 YES
72 06/08/2019 10:58:11 06/08/2019 12:30:50 YES
73 06/08/2019 12:30:50 06/08/2019 12:40:54 YES
```

In the sequences shown after 73, sequence 10771 ... onwards, why are they shown? Can I clean those sequences?

Comment: I suppose these archive log with a higher number are from a previous incarnation. They have an older RESETLOGS_TIME than your current archive.  There is no need to cleanup. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Exactly, they are from a previous incarnation, it turns out that I previously had asm and migrated everything to the operating system's filesystem, I did this with RMAN and had to do an open resetlogs. I want to clean them simply to have a more clear view because the informatics who attend the system do not have much experience in these matters and I do not personally administer that system, I suppose it should be possible to clean but I am not sure how to proceed.